# What makes the Var(x)+Var(y)=var(x+y) property important?

Tags: probability, statistics

What makes the Var(x)+Var(y)=var(x+y) property important?

It was taught in my statistics class

Comment: 'important' is a very vague term. If you want a sensible answer you should formulate your question more clearly.

Comment: I've up-voted this question.  Its vote total is now $-1$.  It's a good question.  I'd down-vote "Alex"'s comment if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 18th century Abraham de Moivre considered this problem (his account of which you can find in his book *The Doctrine of Chances*: If you toss a fair coin $1800$ times, what is the probability that the number of heads in in a specified interval, for example at least $880$ but no more than $906$?  In the course of solving that problem, he first introduced the "bell-shaped curve"
$$
\varphi(x) = \text{constant}\cdot e^{-x^2/2}
$$
where the "constant" is chosen so as to make this a probability density function.  (De Moivre found the constant numerically, and James Stirling later showed that it's $1/\sqrt{2\pi\,{}}$.  This is the "normal distribution" with expectation $0$ and variance $1$.  It follows that the normal density with expectation $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ has density
$$
x\mapsto \text{same constant}\cdot\frac1\sigma\varphi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right).
$$
De Moivre found that the distribution of the number of heads can be made as close as desired to the normal distribution with the right values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ by making the number of tosses large enough, and $1800$ was plenty.

But how do you know the right values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$?

In the case of $\sigma$, you just use the fact that **the variance of the sum of independent random variable is the sum of the variances,** i.e. the property of variances that you learned in your statistics class.  Other simple measures of statistical dispersion lack that property, and so cannot be applied to this coin-toss problem.

It's used in statistics all the time.  How do you know that if you take a sample of size $n$ from a population that's not necessarily normally distributed, you can use the two numbers
$$
\bar x \pm 1.96\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
as endpoints of a $95\%$ confidence interval for the population mean, where $S$ is the sample standard deviation?  In particular, where does "$S/\sqrt{n}$ come from?  The answer is that it comes from that same property of variances that you were taught.

Comment: To Hardy- is it the only important aspect of the property?

Comment: @Victor : Probably not.

Comment: Hardy- Can you name one more important aspect to me please?

Comment: The property in question also arises in studying stochastic processes with independent increments.

Comment: To Hardy- I will learn stochastic process in the future, please answer it in detail if you have time.

Comment: to Hardy- is it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process you talking about?

Comment: That's one example; there are many others.  Including Poisson processes.

Comment: To Hardy: Thank you very much